# Nextjs Routing with activeClassName and Ant Design Menus

Tags: reactjs, antd, next.js

Potentially dumb question- Antd uses an `selectedKeys` field to determine which items inside a menu should be highlighted, and Nextjs uses an `activeClassName` parameter in the `Link` component to provide a class to be added when a page is currently active.
How does one best design a navigation page in Nextjs using the Ant Design menus and to reconcile these two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nextjs withROuter](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#using-a-higher-order-component) to get the router object, use that to determinate which is the selectedKey

Comment: updated to the official docs instead of the blog post, should be more clear